# Sub routine for OnClick procedure in GridView is not executing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, onclick

We have a GridView with a 2 buttons. One of the buttons is a select button and the other is a one without a command. It is supposed to activate an OnClick sub routine. The sub routine is not executing.

Here is the markup of the GridView with the buttons:

```
        <asp:GridView
            ID="GridViewParentsSummary" 
            runat="server" 
            AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID"
            >

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="ID" 
                    HeaderText="ID" 
                    SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherName" 
                    HeaderText="FatherName" 
                    SortExpression="FatherName" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="MotherName" HeaderText="MotherName" 
                    SortExpression="MotherName" />

                <asp:ButtonField 
                    ButtonType="Button" 
                    CommandName="Select" 
                    Text="Select Details" />

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonNewPersonToReleaseChildren" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="false" 
                            Text="New Person To Release Children"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                            OnClick="NewPersonToReleaseChildren" />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the VB.Net code-behind coding with the sub routines for the buttons:

```
Protected Sub GridViewParentsSummary_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndexChanged

    IntParentsID = GridViewParentsSummary.DataKeys(GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndex).Value

    Response.Redirect("AuthorizationForChildReleaseDetails.aspx")
End Sub

Protected Sub NewPersonToReleaseChildren(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    blnAddModeIsSelected = True

    MsgBox("The button was clicked.")

    Response.Redirect("AuthorizationForChildReleaseDetails.aspx")
End Sub
```

I'm sure I am missing some coding but don't know what that could be because the sub routine for the Select button works, but not the sub routine for NewPersonToReleaseChildren.

Comment: How are you sure it's not called? What is `MsgBox("...")` doing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The message box is not displayed when I click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnDel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-delete.gif" CommandName="del"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

use aspButton or Imagebutton in gridview,in code behind:

```
Protected Sub gridview1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gridview1.RowCommand
    Dim myId As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString 
    If  e.CommandName = "del"  Then

    ElseIf e.CommandName = "upd" Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. We tried to use e.CommandArgument but kept getting error messages. It turned out that we needed to enter a sub routine name in OnRowCommand of the GridView such as OnRowCommand="myGV_RowCommand" and we made a sub route called OnRowCommand="myGV_RowCommand" to handle it with this signature: Protected Sub myGV_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) That's why nothing was executing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Handles Handles NewPersonToReleaseChildren.Click` to your handler

```
Protected Sub NewPersonToReleaseChildren(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewPersonToReleaseChildren.Click

    blnAddModeIsSelected = True

    //MsgBox("The button was clicked.")

    Response.Redirect("AuthorizationForChildReleaseDetails.aspx")
End Sub
```

I don't think there is anything like `MsgBox` in asp.net. If the `Handles` does not work, replace that line with `Throw New Exception("My Button was called")` or put a break point on that line and press F5